# Unable to set value to select box in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

Unable to set Select field value through ref in antd

```
<Select
  allowClear
  showSearch
  placeholder="Please select"
  className="onclick_field_width"
  ref={ref}
>
  <Select.Option className="option-tab" value="Fulltime">
    Fulltime
  </Select.Option>
  <Select.Option className="option-tab" value="Internal Contractor">
    Internal Contractor
  </Select.Option>
  <Select.Option className="option-tab" value="Third Party Contractor">
    Third Party Contractor
  </Select.Option>
</Select>
```

using below code to get ref value but getting undefined.

```
<button onClick={() => handleRef()}>Clear field</button>;

const handleRef = () => {
  console.log("show ref::", ref.current.value);
};
```

if I use the same code with `<Input/>` field it works like a charm
ref.current.input.value.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ant Design `Select` component does not bind any values to `ref` you pass as you expect like a native HTML element. It had only `focus`, `blur`, `scrollTo` functions.

To achieve what you are trying, you can use `useState` hook and make `Select` a controlled component like below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Fulltime");

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        style={{
          width: 200
        }}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <Select.Option className="option-tab" value="Fulltime">
          Fulltime
        </Select.Option>
        <Select.Option className="option-tab" value="Internal Contractor">
          Internal Contractor
        </Select.Option>
        <Select.Option className="option-tab" value="Third Party Contractor">
          Third Party Contractor
        </Select.Option>
      </Select>
      <button onClick={() => handleClear()}>Clear field</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit Basic Usage - antd@4.22.5 (forked)]

Comment: @Nirmesh Rastogi, check this out !!

Comment: This i am already aware of. The problem is i have multiple select box in a row in like editable grid and on uncheck on that row i wanted to clear all selected dropdown at once so i was thinking of some class or ref based approach because onchange i am already using to set selected value. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73360584/reset-antd-select-field-with-ref
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKQJU.png